# What's a good undefined-size data structure for accessing by index?

Tags: c++, containers, std

I need some data structure with an unknown size that will support the following:

- push data by index. That is each item will consist of 2 things: an index (might be not continuous. Namely 1,3,7...), and something else called `data`:

  ```
  struct data
  {
      float par[PARAMETERS];
      int cluster;
      bool visited;
      bool noise;
  };
  ```

  so a data-push would look something like this:

  ```
  data d;
  //some work on d...
  temp.i = 2;
  temp.data = d;
  vec.pushback(temp);
  ```
- accessibility by index. Namely say the vector is named `vec`, then i want to be able to access it by  `vec[i]`. So for example:

  ```
  vec[i].visited = true;
  ```

**edit (another feature):**

- i will also need to insert multiple data per index. I mean, if i insert some index and data and the index already exists, then i want it to just append the data to that index.

I thought of a vector of int and data:

```
typedef std::vector<int,data> Vec;
```

but this doesn't support accessing the `Vec` by the `int` index.

A second thought was a vector of maps:

```
typedef std::vector<std::map<int,data>> Vec;
```

but that's also doesn't support access by index.

Comment: Why not just use `std::map<int, data>`? Gives you access by index, supports sparse indices, enforces unique indices, etc.

Comment: Did you mean `typedef vector<data> Vec;` instead of `typedef vector<int, data> Vec;`

Comment: I agree with std::map, but depending on the size of PARAMETERS may use dynamically allocated data instances. Because, depending on the operations you perform, the data gets copied. Thus: std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<data> >

Comment: @tillaert: a plain vector probably isn't wanted here, because the indices are not necessarily continuous. Sparse indices might need a very large vector, which could be quite inefficient.

Comment: @Rook, you're right I've updated it.

Comment: @Rook I know a plain vector isn't wanted here. But `vector<int, data>` is a vector of ints, with `data` as allocator class.

Comment: @tillaert sure, but that's a small detail compared to its underlying indequacy ;-)

Comment: If you support multiple data per index, and you access the element by index, what should happen? Editing all objects, just the first one, or a random one?

Comment: @MatthiasB i'll probably use `multimap`. let's say for now i only want the `size()` feature. i mean, i need to only how many `data` each `index` holds? is that possible or should i iterate through the `multimap` and do the calculations by my own?

Comment: yes, multimap supports this (using `count` or `equal_range`). If that's really what you need I cannot say. Maybe you could explain what you want to achieve (and thus solve the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))

Answer (score 2):

Why not use just a normal map?

For example, `typedef std::map<int,data> myMap;`.

I don't see a need for anything fancier than this.

Comment: Because for each `index` i will be pushing `data`.
So one index would have more than one `data`.

Comment: Isn't that the whole point? If you mean that you want to combine both your index and data into a single insertion, you may also want to take a look at: `typedef std::set<std::pair<int,data>> mySet;`, although this is very similar to the `map` idea and more verbose.

Comment: Just saw your edit. A map guarantees one `data` per `index`. You may be confusing it with `multimap`, which indeed allows multiple `data` per `index`. If you try to insert a new `data` to an existing `index` for a **map**, then the insertion will fail with an exception. If you use the `insert` method of the map when inserting (and don't use the overriden `[]` operator), then you can catch the failure and it will give you an iterator to the previously inserted `data`.

Comment: @AlaaM your question doesn't say there will be multiple `data` instances per index, please update it. Also, it is trivial to extend this solution to `std::map<int, std::vector<data>>`

Comment: @AlaaM Or use a `multimap`, as I described in my last comment.

Comment: so `multimap` allows inserting multiple `data` per index by just `.pushback()`? and if it's the same 'index' it appends it to it?

Comment: It doesn't use `push_back`, that's a vector-specific function. You can use either the overloaded `operator []` or the `insert` method. See the MSDN description here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ka6hya8.aspx.

Comment: Simply speaking, map only allows a single `data` per `index` whereas multimap (the *multi* is the clue) allows multiple `data` per `index`.

Comment: @djikay ok so i defined: `typedef multimap<int,data> Clusters;` and declared `Clusters clusters;`, but when i type `clusters[i].` it doesn't pop out the suggestions window (i.e "IntelliSense: No members available"). Shouldn't it give me `data`'s fields?

Comment: Sometimes intellisense takes time to update. But are you sure you haven't made a typo? In your comment you said that you declared `clusters` and then are using `cluster[i]` (no **s**).

Comment: Also, I may have misled you slightly. `multimap` doesn't have an overloaded `operator []`, I just checked the help page. I assumed it did, because the normal `map` has it (you know what they say about assumptions...). Anyway, you'll have to use the methods provided to achieve what you want, e.g. `.insert()`: `Clusters clusters;` and `clusters.insert(std::make_pair(index, data));`

Comment: ok... i see. another question: if 1 index has more than 1 data, how can i access those multiple data? i mean, if i search a particular index, which data do i get?

Comment: SO frowns upon extended discussion in comments. I can't help you with everything (I'm at work and I'm about to go home). All I can do is give you some direction and hope you can build on that. Consider using the `equal_range` method to find the data associated with an index. Search on Google and you'll find a lot of multimap examples/samples to get you going. I've tried to be as helpful as I could.

Comment: This can hopefully get you started: http://tux4life.wordpress.com/2009/06/24/finding-elements-in-a-stl-multimap/.

Answer (score 0):

How about a hashmap? `data` would be the name of your struct. Each index would map to a unique instance of `data`.

```
std::hash_map<int, data>
```